# Can all Lissajous curves be described by an implicit equation?

Tags: parametric, algebraic-curves, chebyshev-polynomials

I was trying to find the implicit form of the parametric curve $L(x(t),y(t))$ where $x(t)=5\cos\left(3 \pi t +\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and $y(t)=3cos\left(6 \pi t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. At the end I wasted a lot of time and paper because I couldn't figure out the implicit expression (maybe I just didn't manipulate it properly). On the other hand, I saw a paper where these curves where described using Chebyshev's polynomials. I just want to know if the implicit form can be found without recurring to these polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd break it down like:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{5}
&=\cos(3\pi t + \pi/4)\\
&=\cos(3\pi t)\cos(\pi/4)-\sin(3\pi t)\sin(\pi/4)\\
&=kc-ks&k=1/\sqrt{2},c=\cos(3\pi t),s=\sin(3\pi t)
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{y}{3}
&=\cos(6\pi t - \pi/4)\\
&=\cos(6\pi t)\cos(\pi/4)+\sin(6\pi t)\sin(\pi/4)\\
&=\left(\cos^2(3\pi t)-\sin^2(3\pi t)\right)\cos(\pi/4)+2\sin(3\pi t)\cos(3\pi t)\sin(\pi/4)\\
&=kc^2-ks^2+2kcs
\end{align}
$$

So now given these two relations along with $c^2+s^2=1$, you'd like to eliminate $c$ and $s$. It seems helpful to square sides of the first relation so it can be quadratic in $c$ and $s$ like the other two. Normalize by $k^2$, and by $k$ in the second relation.

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^2&= c^2  +s^2  - 2cs
&\frac{y}{3k}&=                 c^2  -s^2  + 2cs
&1&=                            c^2  +s^2
\end{align}
$$

This is now three equations with three things to eliminate ($c^2,s^2,cs$). We'd like to have more equations than things to eliminate. To that end, square the sides of each equation. Also take each pairwise product of two left sides, equal to the corresponding product of right sides. This makes six equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^4  &= c^4 - 4c^3s + 6c^2s^2 - 4cs^3 + s^4 \\
\left(\frac{y}{3k}\right)^2  &= c^4 + 4c^3s + 2c^2s^2 - 4cs^3 + s^4 \\
1                            &= c^4         + 2c^2s^2         + s^4 \\
\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^2\frac{y}{3k}
                             &= c^4         - 4c^2s^2 + 4cs^3 - s^4 \\
\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^2  &= c^4 - 2c^3s + 2c^2s^2 - 2cs^3 + s^4 \\
\frac{y}{3k}                 &= c^4 + 2c^3s           + 2cs^3 - s^4
\end{align}
$$

Now we can try to use linear algebra to find a relation on the six vectors from $\mathbb{R}^5$ suggested by the right sides. Row reduction leads to:

$$-2(\text{right}_1)-(\text{right}_2)-(\text{right}_3)-2(\text{right}_4)+4(\text{right}_5)+2(\text{right}_6)=0$$

Therefore

$$-2\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^4-\left(\frac{y}{3k}\right)^2-1-2\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^2\frac{y}{3k}+4\left(\frac{x}{5k}\right)^2+2\frac{y}{3k}=0$$

[Here is that implicit plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B5%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E4-%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B3%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E2-1-2%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B5%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E2%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B3%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%2B4%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B5%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E2%2B2%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B3%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%3D0) and [here is the original parametric plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D5cos%283pi+t%2Bpi%2F4%29%2C+y%3D3cos%286pi+t-pi%2F4%29), confirming a match.

Comment: would this work on a [fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785293/cartesian-solutions-of-parametric-equations-pikachu-on-a-graph-in-one-equation) as well?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi The thing here was showing how this one particular example is barely within reason for doing by hand. Ultimately because the period of one coordinate was twice the period of the other, and these were basic trig functions, that led to the relation being 4th degree, so not too big. And toward the end there I used linear algebra on a $5\times 6$ matrix, sort of at the edge of what I'm personally willing to do by hand.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  I think that in general, as Angina explains, this can still be done. But in general, it will be unwieldly for doing it by hand. And yes, I think it is the same for finite sums of trig functions (I'm not calling them "series" because you just have partial sums) according to Angina's explanation. But with sums, the degree of the relation will grow significantly.

Comment: Yes, I understand the complexity, infact the fourier parametrics indicated in that link contain 2000 fourier coefn.. My basic question is, can I get a closed form. From your preceeding 2 comments, I could take away that, this can be done. If so, can you generate a proof and possibly answer the question? Sorry for the self promotion but this answer and Angina's regained my willingness to get a conclusive opinion about that. Thanks

Comment: Follow Angina's explanation. Unless I miss something, it applies to your Fourier sums scenario too.

Answer (score 3):

These curves can always be given by an implicit relation. If you have
a curve given by
$$x=a\cos(mt+c)$$
$$y=b\cos(nt+d)$$
with $m$ and $n$ positive integers, then you can use addition formulae
for sine and cosine to rewrite as
$$x=f(\cos t,\sin t)$$
$$y=g(\cos t,\sin t)$$
for some polynomials $f$ and $g$. If we let $u=\tan (t/2)$ we can use the half-angle
formulae $\cos t=(1-u^2)/(1+u^2)$ and $\sin t=2u/(1+u^2)$ to rewrite these
in the form
$$(1+u^2)^Mx=F(u)$$
$$(1+u^2)^Ny=G(u)$$
for polynomials $F$ and $G$. Now eliminate $u$ from these equations (say by resultants
or Groebner bases) to get a polynomial equation
$$H(x,y)=0.$$

I don't recommend you do this by hand....

Comment: would this work on a [fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785293/cartesian-solutions-of-parametric-equations-pikachu-on-a-graph-in-one-equation) as well?